# Gridview scroll not working in scrollview

Tags: android, gridview

in my layout i am using scroll view as parent layout, grid view is child layout, 
gallery images are working fine in patriot mode, when ever rotate the screen into landscape grid view scrolling is not working.

please help me.

Comment: I'd be careful using a grid view in a scroll view. If you must, I'd use a custom version of each view and have only one catch and propigate touch events. Otherwise the scroll will break if one view is blocking touch events from reaching the other.

Comment: don't ever put a gridview (or a listview for that matters) in a scrollview. It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to give the GridView a fixed size inside ScrollView, and enable scrolling it.

To do so, you would have to implement a new class extending GridView and override onTouchEvent() to call requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true).
Thus, the parent view will leave the Grid intercept touch events.

GridViewScrollable.java:

```
package com.example;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class GridViewScrollable extends GridView {

    public GridViewAdjuntos(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public GridViewAdjuntos(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public GridViewAdjuntos(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        // Called when a child does not want this parent and its ancestors to intercept touch events.
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Add it in your layout with the characteristics you want, inside the ScrollView:

```
<com.example.GridViewScrollable
android:id="@+id/myGVS"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

And just get it in your activity:

```
GridViewScrollable myGridView = (GridViewScrollable) findViewById(R.id.myGVS);
```

I hope it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

Simply enable your GridView Property

android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" It will work.